# SAS: Create Variable from Proc SQL to use in Macro

Tags: sas

I want to count the number of unique items in a variable (call it "categories") then use that count to set the number of iterations in a SAS macro (i.e., I'd rather not hard code the number of iterations).

I can get a count like this:

```
proc sql;
        select count(*)
        from (select DISTINCT categories from myData);
quit;
```

I can run a macro like this:

```
%macro superFreq;
    %do i=1 %to &iterationVariable;
        Proc freq data=myData;
        table var&i / out=var&i||freq;
    run;
%mend superFreq;
%superFreq
```

I want to know how to get the count into the iteration variable so that the macro iterates as many times as there are unique values in the variable "categories".

Sorry if this is confusing. Happy to clarify if need be. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `into` clause in `proc sql`:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select max(age), 
         max(height), 
         max(weight) 
  into :max_age, 
       :max_height, 
       :max_weight 
  from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put &=max_age &=max_height &=max_weight;
```

**Result:**

```
MAX_AGE=      16 MAX_HEIGHT=      72 MAX_WEIGHT=     150
```

You can also select a list of results into a macro variable by combining the `into` clause with the `separated by` clause:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select name into :list_of_names separated by ' ' from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put &=list_of_names;
```

**Result:**

```
LIST_OF_NAMES=Alfred Alice Barbara Carol Henry James Jane Janet Jeffrey John Joyce Judy Louise Mary Philip Robert Ronald Thomas
```

William

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response. I'm new to SAS macros, so I look forward to playing around with this.